# Custom request URL

Tags: spring-saml

I am configuring a saml app that will receive requests from adfs.  I would like to use a custom URL to receive the request.  Here is my configuration:

```
<http servlet-api-provision="false"  entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true" >
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="memberAuthenticationFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" username="ANONYMOUS" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/login/index.htm"/>
</http>
<beans:bean id="ssoAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="${ssoNonMemberRedirectUrl}" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/auth.htm"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <filter-chain pattern="/auth.htm" filters="ssoAuthenticationFilter"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
    </filter-chain-map>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetails">
        <beans:bean class="com.wigitsrus.wigits.security.MemberDetailsService" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>
<beans:bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
<beans:bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>
<beans:bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <beans:property name="entityId" value="http://wigitsrus.com"/>
        <beans:property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://wigitsrus.com/wigits"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<!-- Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers -->
<beans:bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <beans:constructor-arg>
                            <beans:value type="java.io.File">classpath:com/wigitsrus/wigits/security/saml/FederationMetadata.xml</beans:value>
                        </beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <beans:property name="alias" value="http://theidp.com"/>
                        <beans:property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                        <beans:property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                        <beans:property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                        <beans:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="defaultIDP" value="http://theidp.com"/>
    <beans:property name="refreshCheckInterval" value="0"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<beans:bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB">
    <beans:property name="scheme" value="https"/>
    <beans:property name="serverName" value="wigitsrus.com"/>
    <beans:property name="serverPort" value="443"/>
    <beans:property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="false"/>
    <beans:property name="contextPath" value="/wigits"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<beans:bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <beans:property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
<beans:bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0">
        <beans:bean class="com.wigitsrus.wigits.security.MemberLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<beans:bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0">
        <beans:bean class="com.wigitsrus.wigits.security.MemberLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<beans:bean id="samlProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <beans:ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <beans:ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <beans:ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <beans:ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<beans:bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<beans:bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<beans:bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<beans:bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<beans:bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<beans:bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<beans:bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </beans:constructor-arg>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:property name="processor">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<beans:bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

<!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
<beans:bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize"/>
<beans:bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>


<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<beans:bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="classpath:/com/wigitsrus/wigits/security/saml/sso-test.jks"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${keystore.password}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="${private.key.alias}" value="${keystore.password}" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="${private.key.alias}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

The problem I'm running into is:
    Endpoint with message binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST and filter URL /auth.htm wasn't found

When I step through the code in SAMLUtil.getEndpoint the endpoint that seems like it should match is using location: https://www.wigitsrus.com/wigit/saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias

How do I set the location property used by the post endpoint so it matches the requestURL?

Comment: can u share the complete xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is:

- download your currently generated metadata from `https://wigitsrus.com/wigits/saml/metadata` and store it in (for example) `classpath:com/wigitsrus/wigits/security/saml/sp.xml`
- manually modify the file and replace `Location` in `AssertionConsumerService` elements with `https://wigitsrus.com/wigits/auth.htm`
- add the metadata to the list inside `CachingMetadataManager` for example like this:

  ```
  <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
      <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
              <constructor-arg>
                  <value type="java.io.File">classpath:com/wigitsrus/wigits/security/saml/sp.xml</value>
              </constructor-arg>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
          </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
              <property name="alias" value="defaultAlias"/>
              <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
              <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
              <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
              <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
              <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="true"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="true"/>
          </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
  ```
- make sure to upload your new SP metadata to the IDP

System will now no longer use the `MetadataGenerator` and it should expect the SAML response to arrive at the `https://wigitsrus.com/wigits/auth.htm` endpoint.

If you're willing to live with URL `https://wigitsrus.com/wigits/auth.htm/alias/defaultAlias`, all you should need to do is:

- upload the metadata from `https://wigitsrus.com/wigits/saml/metadata` to the IDP, the AssertionConsumerServices should already contain the correct URL
- change the `filterChain` to have `pattern="/auth.htm/**"`